# Composition of high complex queries in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

My question is: How can I replace some complex calculation using custom defined functions in such way that the statements from the query who called the function affect the function output in postgres? I will give an example to clarify it a little bit more. Assume we have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (my_id INT, cat_col VARCHAR(1), col1 INT, col2 INT);
INSERT INTO test
VALUES
(0, 'a', 1, 3),
(1, 'a', 4, 5),
(2, 'b', 2, 8),
(3, 'b', 3, 6);
```

Consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT cat_col, SUM(col1 * col2)
FROM test
WHERE my_id >= 1
GROUP BY cat_col;
```

Let's pretend the statement `SUM(col1 * col2)` is very complex and we cannot easily put it in the query just like we did, how can I write a function to replace this statement? Something like:

```sql
SELECT cat_col, f(params)
FROM test
WHERE my_id >= 1
GROUP BY cat_col;
```

I think there must be a way to pass the filtered and grouped column to the function, but I do not have two much experience with user defined functions and after reading the postgres documentation i could not come up with a solution yet. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps a materialized view?

Answer (score 1):

You should know that when you declare a function, the query will be much slower.
Aggregate functions are faster than calling a user defined function.
Nevertheless, function could look like (PG/PL SQL block):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum_up(i integer, y integer) RETURNS integer AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN i + y;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

You could also use SQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION sum_up(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    AS 'select $1 + $2;'
    LANGUAGE SQL
    IMMUTABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

You can read more about declaring different types of function in documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: Neither of your functions worked, I typed: ```SELECT cat_col, sum_up(col1::INT, col2::INT)
FROM test
WHERE my_id >= 1
GROUP BY cat_col;``` and I got an error saying that test.col1 should be in the group by

Comment: Oh ye, it should be in group by expression then:
`SELECT cat_col, sum_up(col1::INT, col2::INT) FROM test WHERE my_id >= 1 GROUP BY cat_col,sum_up(col1::INT, col2::INT);`
It will work, but this is ugly as hell.
That is also why you shouldnt write separate functions that replace aggregate functions.

In that case you would need to create your own aggregate, it is described in the docs aswell:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html#:~:text=Aggregate%20functions%20in%20PostgreSQL%20are,successive%20input%20row%20is%20processed.